# Python - Pause entire script every 10 minutes

Tags: python, pause

Need a way to pause a script for 2 minutes after letting it run for 10 minutes first, and then have this process repeat itself. I need the script itself to continue running throughout the 10 minutes.

I tried using threading but found that it didn't actually pause the the rest of the script.

EDIT: Added code to give perspective. Hopefully this helps to explain my issue.

Comment: "A simple `time.sleep()` doesn't work as it stops the rest of the script from running" - isn't "pausing a script for 2 minutes" exactly the same as stopping the entire script for 2 minutes? Also you say that threading "didn't actually pause the the rest of the script" - so do you want to pause the (entire) script or not?

Comment: Apologies - that was confusing. What I meant is that I wasn't able to find a way to let the script itself run for 10 mins, pause for 2 mins, then continue running for 10 mins etc

Comment: Well, after the edit, this shows no attempt on trying to solve the problem at all.

Comment: @MattC, running for 10 mins, pausing, then running again, then pausing etc sounds like a great use-case for a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a nice loop where you can implant the pause, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
...

def start():
    lastsleep = datetime.now()                                    # <-- new
    while True:
        openBank()
        gear()
        invCheck()
        timer = random.uniform(33, 37)
        print("Sleep time: %s" % timer)
        time.sleep(timer)

        if (datetime.now() - lastsleep) > timedelta(minutes=10):  # <-- new
            time.sleep(2*60)
            lastsleep = datetime.now()
```

Note that this will not sleep exactly after 10 minutes, but whenever 10 minutes are over and it reaches the checkpoint. This may be 10:12 or 13:47 minutes, depending on what the other code (`openBank()`, `gear()` etc.) does before.

---

Answer before code was shown:

The problem is: we have no information on how your code looks like.

If you have

```
something = getSomething()
something.DoSomeVeryExpensiveOperation()  # takes 25 minutes
```

there's no good way to interrupt or pause that method after 10 minutes.

The only way I can think of as a generic method is like this:

- use multiprocessing
- monitor the process from outside
- after 10 minutes, suspend all threads of the process
- sleep 2 minutes
- resume all threads of the process

Before you do that, you should know [why you should never suspend a thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573)

Comment: Thanks very much!
It works for the first pause, however upon reaching the same point again it spits out this error:

`if (datetime.now()-lastsleep) > timedelta(minutes=10):`


`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Comment: @MattC Are you sure you haven't forgotten the braces here? `lastsleep = datetime.now()`

Comment: My bad, I missed a single brace on the very bottom line.